# JS script to change input type from checkbox to radio?

Tags: javascript, input, checkbox, replace, radio-button

I have a mailpoet form with a list so people can choose out of multiple subscriptions.

```
  <label class="mailpoet_segment_label">title</label>
  <label class="mailpoet_checkbox_label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mailpoet_checkbox" name="data[form_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz][]" value="9" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="segments" data-parsley-errors-container=".mailpoet_error_segments" data-parsley-required-message="Selecteer een lijst" data-parsley-multiple="dataform_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz" wtx-context="2278B8F3-5F48-4047-9B6D-131ED484ADF5">
    Alle Job Alerts</label>
  <label class="mailpoet_checkbox_label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mailpoet_checkbox" name="data[form_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz][]" value="4" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="segments" data-parsley-errors-container=".mailpoet_error_segments" data-parsley-required-message="Selecteer een lijst" data-parsley-multiple="dataform_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz" wtx-context="DB7A7A5C-BA6F-4508-9F8F-958BD0B69F58">
    List 1</label>
  <label class="mailpoet_checkbox_label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mailpoet_checkbox" name="data[form_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz][]" value="5" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="segments" data-parsley-errors-container=".mailpoet_error_segments" data-parsley-required-message="Selecteer een lijst" data-parsley-multiple="dataform_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz" wtx-context="0F392140-FE75-45C1-970E-AC57D9011B1D">
    List 2</label>
  <label class="mailpoet_checkbox_label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mailpoet_checkbox" name="data[form_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz][]" value="8" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="segments" data-parsley-errors-container=".mailpoet_error_segments" data-parsley-required-message="Selecteer een lijst" data-parsley-multiple="dataform_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz" wtx-context="415437C4-9B0D-43BD-9E6D-091EA5F12EC8">
    List 3</label>
  <label class="mailpoet_checkbox_label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mailpoet_checkbox" name="data[form_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz][]" value="6" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="segments" data-parsley-errors-container=".mailpoet_error_segments" data-parsley-required-message="Selecteer een lijst" data-parsley-multiple="dataform_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz" wtx-context="28C9611D-DCD1-46BE-8164-FFD1EFCCE257">
    List 4</label>
  <label class="mailpoet_checkbox_label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mailpoet_checkbox" name="data[form_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz][]" value="7" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="segments" data-parsley-errors-container=".mailpoet_error_segments" data-parsley-required-message="Selecteer een lijst" data-parsley-multiple="dataform_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz" wtx-context="33C371EB-732F-4D1F-B5B2-1ED87F3A524C">
    List 5</label>
  <span class="mailpoet_error_segments"></span>
```

Problem is, I only want them to pick one. Basically, The list does not need te be a checkbox, but a radio button (only one selection allowed).

This Is the way the list is generated, zo I cant edit the html.

What would be the right script to replace the input type to radio (and allow only one selection.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all the checkboxes. Then set the attribute `type` from `checkbox` to `radio`.

Just make sure that all radioboxes have the same name, this way you can only select one.

```js
// Select by input type
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
// Select by class
// const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".mailpoet_checkbox");

checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.setAttribute("type", "radio");
});
```

```html
<label class="mailpoet_segment_label">title</label>
  <label class="mailpoet_checkbox_label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mailpoet_checkbox" name="data[form_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz][]" value="9" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="segments" data-parsley-errors-container=".mailpoet_error_segments" data-parsley-required-message="Selecteer een lijst" data-parsley-multiple="dataform_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz" wtx-context="2278B8F3-5F48-4047-9B6D-131ED484ADF5">
    Alle Job Alerts</label>
  <label class="mailpoet_checkbox_label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mailpoet_checkbox" name="data[form_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz][]" value="4" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="segments" data-parsley-errors-container=".mailpoet_error_segments" data-parsley-required-message="Selecteer een lijst" data-parsley-multiple="dataform_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz" wtx-context="DB7A7A5C-BA6F-4508-9F8F-958BD0B69F58">
    List 1</label>
  <label class="mailpoet_checkbox_label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mailpoet_checkbox" name="data[form_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz][]" value="5" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="segments" data-parsley-errors-container=".mailpoet_error_segments" data-parsley-required-message="Selecteer een lijst" data-parsley-multiple="dataform_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz" wtx-context="0F392140-FE75-45C1-970E-AC57D9011B1D">
    List 2</label>
  <label class="mailpoet_checkbox_label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mailpoet_checkbox" name="data[form_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz][]" value="8" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="segments" data-parsley-errors-container=".mailpoet_error_segments" data-parsley-required-message="Selecteer een lijst" data-parsley-multiple="dataform_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz" wtx-context="415437C4-9B0D-43BD-9E6D-091EA5F12EC8">
    List 3</label>
  <label class="mailpoet_checkbox_label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mailpoet_checkbox" name="data[form_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz][]" value="6" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="segments" data-parsley-errors-container=".mailpoet_error_segments" data-parsley-required-message="Selecteer een lijst" data-parsley-multiple="dataform_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz" wtx-context="28C9611D-DCD1-46BE-8164-FFD1EFCCE257">
    List 4</label>
  <label class="mailpoet_checkbox_label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mailpoet_checkbox" name="data[form_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz][]" value="7" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="segments" data-parsley-errors-container=".mailpoet_error_segments" data-parsley-required-message="Selecteer een lijst" data-parsley-multiple="dataform_field_YzQxYmU0Njc5OTk5X3NlZ21lbnRz" wtx-context="33C371EB-732F-4D1F-B5B2-1ED87F3A524C">
    List 5</label>
  <span class="mailpoet_error_segments"></span>
```